# Counter is not incrementing properly

Tags: c, count, integer, counter, getchar

my counter does not seem to increment (for c programming)

```
int ch;
int counterX = 0;
int counterY = 0;

while(( ch = getchar()) != EOF ) {

    if (ch == 'X'){
        counterX = counterX + 1;
        }
    if (ch == 'Y'){
        counterY = counterY + 1;
        }
}
```

ive done some testing and I the number for counterX and counterY doesnt seem to increase, regardless of my input. Please help!

Comment: The code you submitted is not compilable because you missed the definition of ch and you are missing the brace enclosing the while loop - that brace could be crucial.

Comment: sry this is just a rough portion of my current program that has the issue. ill edit it properly

Comment: Try to debug your code: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *should* work, provided you add a closing brace, and the rest of the program. And provided you actually *have* `X` and/or `Y` appearing on the input stream.

For example, the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch, counterX = 0, counterY = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch == 'X')
            counterX = counterX + 1;
        if (ch == 'Y')
            counterY = counterY + 1;
    }
    printf ("X = %d, Y = %d\n", counterX, counterY);
    return 0;
}
```

will, when run with `echo XYZZY | testprog`, output:

```
X = 1, Y = 2
```

---

As an aside, if you a good enough C coder to use the:

```
while ((a = something) == somethingElse)
```

construct, you should probably know about the `counterX++` shorthand as well :-)

Comment: yeah my bad, i forgot to put my output inside my loop. thx anyways